# Is it possible to use services like Papertrail for Laravel Vapor?

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

Papertrail works on local and never when deployed to Vapor.

```
'stack' => [
     'driver' => 'stack',
     'channels' => ['papertrail', 'bugsnag'],
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Papertrail Laravel logger doesn't work in serverless environment. I have reached out to Papertrail support for help.

But if you still want to see logs, the solution, in case anyone runs into it after me, is to add the `stderr` stack. Below is my `logging.php` file.

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\NullHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option defines the default log channel that gets used when writing
    | messages to the logs. The name specified in this option should match
    | one of the channels defined in the "channels" configuration array.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channels
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log channels for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Drivers: "single", "daily", "slack", "syslog",
    |                    "errorlog", "monolog",
    |                    "custom", "stack"
    |
    */

    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['vapor', 'bugsnag'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'bugsnag' => [
            'driver' => 'bugsnag',
        ],

        'vapor' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['stderr', 'papertrail'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'critical',
        ],

        'papertrail' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
                'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
            ],
        ],

        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER', "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n"),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => NullHandler::class,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Where does the stderr log output to? By default the vapor logging works out the box (through Amazon cloudwatch). I thought that adding the stderr may make papertrail work but that seems not to be the case.

I am assuming papertrail still does not work with stderr enabled?

Comment: Paper trail said they need vapor to fix the issue

Comment: Do you know of any other logging solutions that allow logs to be filtered/searched in the same way that Papertrail does? Amazon cloudwatch is horrible to use... and vapors GUI logging is not great for any kind of volume

Comment: I haven’t found any yet man. But I will try to make paper trail work by sending logs from CW to Vapor using something like a dedicated Winston logger running in a separate lambda.